control of bifurcation in dynamical system by using normal form and feedback
enter image description here
enter image description here
the book "Approved for public release; distribution is unlimited.
THE CONTROL OF BIFURCATIONS
WITH ENGINEERING APPLICATIONS
by
Osa E. Fitch
Lieutenant Commander, United States Navy
M.S., M.I.T., 1982
Submitted in partial fulfillment of the
requirements for the degree of
DOCTOR OF PHILOSOPHY IN AERONAUTICS AND
ASTRONAUTICS
from the
NAVAL POSTGRADUATE SCHOOL
September, 1997"
page 69>
how we can find defines the transformation matrix Tx to transform the system to Jordan-Brunovsky canonical  form?
